# Error in as.character(split) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r

I am totally newbie to R programming and here is where I stuck.

I was trying to extract the characters in the first column of my table up to "|" in each row with the following code;

```
library(limma)

temp<- read.delim("C:/Users/doe/Desktop/Work/colon_expression/results.txt", sep ="\t", header = T)
temp

temp<-limma::strsplit2(temp,split,"|")[,1]
temp
```

RStudio gives this error;

> Error in as.character(split) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to
>   vector of type 'character'

How can I fix the coercion problem for my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
limma::strsplit2(temp, "|")[,1]
```

You can look into `strsplit2` documentation with `?strsplit2`

Which gives that function `strsplit2` requires two arguments:

- `x`character vector. Here you provided `temp`.
- `split` character to split. Here you just wrote `split`.

So what you need to do is to provide character to split by (ie., replace `split` with `"|"`).

Comment: You could add that `split` is a base R function, i.e., a closure.